# creating new column in table using CASE statement SQL

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I have a table in SQL called 'full_data' which looks like:

```
Date         Product    Size   Currency    Paid
10/11/2020   T-shirt    M      EUR         40.00
09/11/2020   Hoodie     S      USD         60.00
etc...
```

I want to add a new column into the full_data using a CASE statement. The CASE statement is as below:

```
CASE
    WHEN Product = 'Hoodie' AND Size = 'S' THEN 'Small hoodie'
    WHEN Product = 'Hoodie' AND Size = 'M' THEN 'Medium hoodie'
    WHEN Product = 'T-shirt' AND Size = 'S' THEN 'Small shirt'
    WHEN Product = 'T-shirt' AND Size = 'M' THEN 'Medium shirt'
    ELSE 'Other product'
END AS sale_note
```

What would be the right code to use so that the table at the end would look like:

```
sale_note       Date         Product    Size   Currency   Paid
Medium shirt    10/11/2020   T-shirt    M      EUR        40.00
Small hoodie    09/11/2020   Hoodie     S      USD        60.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just put the `case` **expression** in the `select`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Product = 'Hoodie' AND Size = 'S' THEN 'Small hoodie'
             WHEN Product = 'Hoodie' AND Size = 'M' THEN 'Medium hoodie'
             WHEN Product = 'T-shirt' AND Size = 'S' THEN 'Small shirt'
             WHEN Product = 'T-shirt' AND Size = 'M' THEN 'Medium shirt'
             ELSE 'Other product'
        END) AS sale_note,
       fd.*
FROM full_data fd;
```

You can create a view with this information:

```
create view v_full_data as
    SELECT (CASE WHEN Product = 'Hoodie' AND Size = 'S' THEN 'Small hoodie'
                 WHEN Product = 'Hoodie' AND Size = 'M' THEN 'Medium hoodie'
                 WHEN Product = 'T-shirt' AND Size = 'S' THEN 'Small shirt'
                 WHEN Product = 'T-shirt' AND Size = 'M' THEN 'Medium shirt'
                 ELSE 'Other product'
            END) AS sale_note,
           fd.*
    from full_data fd;
```

I don't think Redshift supports generated columns so a view is your best option.